# RegEx expression that will match Date format

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

I have a line with `"1999-08-16"^^xsd:date`. What will be the regex to capture the whole string as `"1999-08-16"^^xsd:date`in flex file? And, is it possible to capture only "1999-08-16" as a string. If yes, then what will be the regex for it in flex?

Comment: A simple regex to match for the date will be `/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/` that will match any numbers in the format 4digit-2digit-2digit which also include invalid dates like `0000-99-99`.

Comment: Now I can capture  `"1999-08-16"`  using `\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\"`. But if I want to capture the whole string as `"1999-08-16"^^xsd:date` then what will be the regex? I have tried with `\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\"\^\^"xsd:date"` but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture whole string `\"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\"\^\^[^ ]*` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^"(\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])-(?:30|31|[12]\d|0?[1-9]))"\^\^xsd:date$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of line
- `\d{4}` - year part
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])` - month, can be:

  - 01-09 or 1-9 (that's why `0?`)
  - 10,11,12 (`1[012]` part)
- `?:` means non-capturing group (if we need just alternating matches
  with `|`, but not outputting them to user)
- `(?:30|31|[12]\d|0?[1-9])` - day part, can be:

  - 30,31,
  - 10-29 (part `[12]\d`)
  - 1-9, or 01-09 (`0?[1-9]`)

    Also we use non-capturing group for matching day
- `$` matches end of line
- Everything in between `""` is captured to standard capturing group, as you need to extract date

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGhmDP/2)

**NOTICE:**
When matching days we put `1-9` day numbers in LAST alternating group:

> (?:30|31|[12]\d|**0?[1-9]**)

that's because regex engine when given alternating matches uses FIRST matched result and other matched alternatives are ignored. For example-
in string `1 11` expression:

- `(?:\d{2}|\d)` gives 2 matches
- `(?:\d|\d{2})` gives 3 matches